# How to allow the thread to sleep at a certain stage?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
@Override
public void run(int interfaceId, int componentId) {
    if (interfaceId == 382 && componentId == 19) {
        player.stopAll();
        player.lock(4);
        player.setNextAnimation(new Animation(6132));
        final WorldTile toTile = new WorldTile(ditch.getRotation() == 3 || ditch.getRotation() == 1 ? ditch.getX() - 1 : player.getX(),
                ditch.getRotation() == 0 || ditch.getRotation() == 2 ? ditch.getY() + 2 : player.getY(), ditch.getPlane());
        player.setNextForceMovement(new ForceMovement(
                new WorldTile(player), 1, toTile, 2,    ditch.getRotation() == 0 || ditch.getRotation() == 2 ? ForceMovement.NORTH : ForceMovement.WEST));
        try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WorldTasksManager.schedule(new WorldTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                player.setNextWorldTile(toTile);
                player.faceObject(ditch);
                player.getControlerManager().startControler("Wilderness");
                player.resetReceivedDamage();
            }
        }, 2);
    } else
        player.closeInterfaces();
    end();
}
```

well as you can see in the middle of the code i added in "Thread.sleep(3000);" because i want the process to stop for just 3 seconds then continue, however when i try to run it the thread sleeping executes before any other code behind it, why so and how will i allow it to execute at the order i want it to?

cheers!

Comment: Is the "any other code behind it" the `WorldTask` below your call to sleep or is it somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead (you may have to move the catch block around):

```
    @Override
 public void run(int interfaceId, int componentId) {

 if (interfaceId == 382 && componentId == 19) {
    System.out.println("Am i printing?????");
    try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WorldTasksManager.schedule(new WorldTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            player.setNextWorldTile(toTile);
            player.faceObject(ditch);
            player.getControlerManager().startControler("Wilderness");
            player.resetReceivedDamage();
        }
    }, 2);

} else
    player.closeInterfaces();
end();

}
```

Comment: never mind i found a solution, thanks for the attempt to help tho :)